# Postgres files postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf - which take priority?

Tags: postgresql

Which of the two postgres configuration files `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` takes priority?

`pg_hba.conf` controls client authentication methods including 'md5' and 'scram-sha-256'

`postgresql.conf` includes an entry for password_encryption which can be 'md5' or 'scram-sha-256' (or blank, I guess)

So if these values aren't set to the same thing, which takes priority?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no priority to choose because they have different purposes.

- `password_encryption` in postgresql.conf tells how to hash a new password when it's changed or a new user is created with a password.
- the field in `pg_hba.conf` tells what kind of authentication scheme should be used when a client that matches the rules attempts to connect.

---

When connecting with a client that **does not support** SCRAM authentication:

If the first line that matches in `pg_hba.conf` for this connection attempt has, in the METHOD field:

- `scram-sha-256`, the connection will be rejected.
- `md5` and the password of this account is stored with an
  `md5` hash (independently of `password_encryption`), the connection
  will succeed.
- `md5` and the password of this account is stored with an
  `scram-sha256` hash (independently of `password_encryption`), the connection will be rejected.

A superuser can check what kind of password is assigned to existing accounts by looking at the hashed passwords in the system table `pg_catalog.pg_authid`.

Comment: So if I'm connecting to the database via an old version of Npgsql that can't cope with scram-sha-256 I need to ensure that NEITHER of these files mention scram-sha-256?

Comment: @ConanTheGerbil: almost. See the edit.